# vsftpd allows connection only from admin user

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have installed vsftpd ftp server on my ubuntu and I can connect only with the admin user (the user that can be sudoed). Also when I'm connecting via ftp I see the home directory of the `admin` user and not the home dir of the `ftp` user. For all other system users I receive a `530 Login incorrect` error when trying to connect.

Any idea what I've been doing wrong?

The home dir of the `ftp` user is `\srv\ftp`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root ftp  4096 sep 26 12:13 ftp
```

This are my config files:

```
# /etc/vsftpd.conf

listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=NO
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

---

```
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required    pam_shells.so
```

---

```
# /etc/ftpusers: list of users disallowed FTP access. See ftpusers(5).

root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news
uucp
nobody
```

Comment: First Error 503 is "Bad sequence of commands." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes , you try to login as a system user ?

Comment: Sorry, I have entered the wrong error code, is 530 Login incorrect. And, yes, I'm trying to connect as a system user.

Comment: witch system user? be a little more verbose please.

Comment: whats in the logfile ? try this chroot_local_user = YES

Comment: Well I'm trying to connect via a normal user account (which exists on my ubuntu) and the system user used by vsftpd is `ftp`

Comment: The content of the log file is: `
Fri Sep 26 12:35:32 2014 [pid 3948] CONNECT: Client "127.0.0.1"
Fri Sep 26 12:35:39 2014 [pid 3947] [mcristea] FAIL LOGIN: Client "127.0.0.1"
Fri Sep 26 12:35:53 2014 [pid 3956] CONNECT: Client "127.0.0.1"
Fri Sep 26 12:36:00 2014 [pid 3955] [admin] OK LOGIN: Client "127.0.0.1"` If I set chroot_local_user = YES I cannot connect with any user (even the admin user doesn't work anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding `/bin/bash` at the end of the username in `/etc/passwd`:

```
mcristea:x:1001:1000::/home/mcristea:/bin/bash
```

Comment: and what was there written?

Comment: just this: `mcristea:x:1001:1000::/home/mcristea`

Comment: try `mcristea:x:1001:1000::/home/mcristea:/bin/false`, this allows the login but gives no shell. `mcristea:x:1001:1000::/home/mcristea:/sbin/nologin` allowes no login (this is the default).